# Avoid Databinding of Menu on each Postback

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I am creating an multi user application where each user have a set of webforms to be accessed and specific set not to be used(almost 30 types of profiles)

I had created two tables Menu Master and Sub menu master  and Added urls and the parent child relation

I am using a  Infragistic WebExplorer as Navigation control inside a usercontrol and I am doing all the data binding inside the Usercontrol codebehind.

My issue is each time when a user click the WebExplorer the control get databinded and the control is re rendered. causing application  very slow

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                loadexplorerebar();


        }



        public void getMenuData()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from MainMenuMaster");

            DataTable dt = ReturnQueryResultDatatable(cmd);

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT        SubMenuMaster.Menu_PK, SubMenuMaster.MenuText, SubMenuMaster.MenuURL, SubMenuMaster.ParentID, SubMenuMaster.isEnable, SubMenuMaster.IsNormal
FROM            SubMenuMaster INNER JOIN
                         UserProfileRights ON SubMenuMaster.Menu_PK = UserProfileRights.Menu_PK
WHERE(UserProfileRights.UserProfile_Pk = @Param2)");
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", int.Parse(Session["UserProfile_Pk"].ToString()));
            DataTable dt2 = ReturnQueryResultDatatable(cmd1);

            Session["MainMenuMaster"] = dt;
            Session["SubMenuMaster"] = dt2;

        }


        public void loadexplorerebar()
        {
            DataTable dt = null;
            DataTable dt2 = null;

            if (Session["MainMenuMaster"]==null || Session["SubMenuMaster"]==null)
            {
                getMenuData();
            }
            else
            {
                dt = (DataTable)Session["MainMenuMaster"];
                dt2 = (DataTable)Session["SubMenuMaster"];

            }            


            if (dt != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    ExplorerBarGroup grp = new ExplorerBarGroup();
                    grp.Text = dt.Rows[i]["MainmenuName"].ToString();
                    this.WebExplorerBar1.Groups.Add(grp);
                    int MAINMENU_PK = int.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["mAINmENU_pk"].ToString());
                    try
                    {

                        DataTable mainmenuchild = dt2.Select("parentid=" + MAINMENU_PK + "").CopyToDataTable();

                        foreach (DataRow drow in mainmenuchild.Rows)
                        {

                            int childid = int.Parse(drow["Menu_PK"].ToString());
                            ExplorerBarItem item = new ExplorerBarItem();
                            item.Text = drow["MenuText"].ToString();
                            item.NavigateUrl = drow["MenuURL"].ToString();
                            grp.Items.Add(item);
                            try
                            {
                                getnewItem(item, childid, dt2);
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {


                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {


                    }


                }


            }

        }



        public void getnewItem(ExplorerBarItem item, int parentid, DataTable mainmenuchild)
        {

            DataTable mainmenuchildtemp = mainmenuchild.Select("parentid=" + parentid + "").CopyToDataTable();
            foreach (DataRow drow in mainmenuchildtemp.Rows)
            {

                try
                {
                    int childid = int.Parse(drow["Menu_PK"].ToString());
                    ExplorerBarItem itemnum = new ExplorerBarItem();
                    itemnum.Text = drow["MenuText"].ToString();
                    itemnum.NavigateUrl = drow["MenuURL"].ToString();
                    item.Items.Add(itemnum);
                    getnewItem(itemnum, childid, mainmenuchild);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ;
                }
            }
        }
```

And My HTML markup is like below

```
<ig:WebExplorerBar ID="WebExplorerBar1" runat="server" Width="250px">
</ig:WebExplorerBar>
```

Can anyone suggest me how to avoid this data binding on each postback

Comment: May be you can persist the data in the viewstate....some IG controls support the possibility to avoid data binding on post and rely on viewstate. You save time in fetching data from repository. Of course you have to avoid load of data checking if postback

Comment: Try setting the autopostback-itemclick and itemselected to off. Then the WebExplorerBar should stop posting back on each item click. http://www.infragistics.com/help/aspnet/infragistics4.web.v16.2~infragistics.web.ui.navigationcontrols.explorerbarautopostbackflags_members

Answer (score 0):

Place Your loadexplorerebar(); method within ! ispostback

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       loadexplorerebar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding Is postback will stop databinding and rendering of infragistic menubar on postback